# SSH to AWS EC2 instance not happening after changing public ip to a new Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have changed the Public IP of my ec2 instance on AWS to a new elastic IP. After doing this I am unable to access the instance via ssh.

I am getting Permission denied error.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Verify your instance name and use ssh -i keys.pem ubuntu@your_new_instance_name.com . Since you switched to use elatic IP your instance name and IP should survive when you restart.

Comment: @dmitryro Do I have to generate new pem file somehow (if it's possible), Or the same pem file will work?

Comment: It should be same pem with same keys if the only thing you did is adding elastic IP - but it's worth verifying what keys are used and uploading the keys.pem from the console. Also don't forget to reduce the permissions to 400